# Objective C - Singleton static method overriding doesn't work for multiple subclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, singleton, instancetype

**What I have**:

I have multiple singletons in my project and they share some scope, fields and functionality. So I decided to structurize them and create a parent class called BaseSingleton. As a singleton, it has `+(instancetype) sharedInstance`, so will all of its subclasses. Right now I have a `BaseSingleton` class and three subclasses:

- PublicApi
- UserService
- OrderStorage

`+(instancetype) sharedInstance` in BaseSingleton has a common implementation:

```
+(instancetype) sharedInstance {
    static BaseSingleton* _sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t once_token;
    dispatch_once(&once_token, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init]; // no override for init method
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

**What I need:**

I need my Singleton subclasses to work properly when `sharedInstance` is invoked on them. Meaning, `PublicApi` returns an instance of `PublicApi`, `UserService` returns `UserService` and `OrderStorage` returns `OrderStorage` instance, **with no need to implement sharedInstance**.

**What the problem is:**:

So I thought that utilizing `instancetype` in `+(instancetype) sharedInstance` would do the work, because using `instancetype` makes class method return **related return type** (read in [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/)). So if called on PublicApi or UserService, `sharedInstance` would return related type, which is PublicApi or UserService respectively (again, without implementing `sharedInstance` in neither of them).

This worked good with only one subclass (`PublicApi`). But when added other two subclasses, Calling `sharedInstance` on some of them would not exactly result in correct return type. So for example, `[PublicApi sharedInstance]` would return an instance of `PublicApi`, But `[UserService sharedInstance]` would also return an instance of `PublicApi`, same thing for `OrderStorage`.

I think the problem lays in static `_sharedInstance` in `[BaseSingleton sharedInstance]` implementation. `[PublicApi sharedInstance]` is called first during application runtime, so `dispatch_once` method instantiates `_sharedInstance` and gives it a `PublicApi` type. Code block inside `dispatch_once` is never executed again, that is why that static variable never changes its type and is returned as `PublicApi` in `[UserService sharedInstance]` and `[OrderStorage sharedInstance]`.

Any elegant way to do what I am asking about? (Besides implementing `sharedInstance` for each subclass of course, that defeats the whole purpose of inheriting from BaseSingleton).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common base class for singletons is a contradiction in itself.

What should be obvious is that with your sharedSingleton implementation, there is only *one* dispatch_once_t token. So the code inside dispatch_once_t will only be executed *once* in your application. There is also only one static variable for _sharedInstance, so it cannot possibly return two different sharedInstance values.

Don't do this.

Comment: I decided to create a base class with only purpose - avoiding code reuse. It really bothered me that all of my singletons had same sharedInstance implementation, except for returned _sharedInstance type. So I tried to figure out the way to refactor this

Comment: @AzaFromKaza For example logically I suppose that `+(instancetype) sharedInstance` will return for me appropriate Type at runtime, but if you can see that only `BaseSingleton` will get an instance, so it does not mind about any other classes, so `BaseSingleton` just want to be initialized once because of dispatch_once and then when you will request it in second time, there is already an `BaseSingleton`and there is no needs to initialize new one.

Answer (score 1):

As said earlier this architecture has issues, that said it's quite possible. In sharedInstance, you need a cascading set of tests for if 'self' (the class) == say [Public class] else ...

Your method then has multiple static variables one per class handled.